# Mobile view using Bootstrap

Tags: html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a simple page as a Sign In form to test mobile devices access.

Live test is at:

> http://jsbin.com/inumud/1/

outside jsbin:

> http://balexandre.com/gk2

If you try to open that URL from a mobile device, **there is no way** one can get into the account and password forms.

I'm using a **very simple form** using [**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) *(v.2.0.4)* and works fine in any desktop, but why can't I access the form input's from a mobile device? 
*(iPhone does not get into the form, Android does not bring keyboard up)*

What do I have to do more just to make it work on a mobile device without redo the hole site in a Mobile framework?

I'm keep trying and trying, but no success so far and it's been several days now, I'm probably miss-seeing something simple and I hope the community could help clear my eyes :)

Comment: Have you tried the form outside of jsbin? (It strikes me that there might be some js conflict happening.)

Comment: I did, cause my website is really outside jsbin and I have the same thing, but here is the same code in my personal space: http://balexandre.com/gk2

Comment: Works fine on WP7. But I see you have a charset problem with your lorem. Could it be ? Anyway, have you tried removing all the javascript ?

Comment: @Sherbrow yes, works on my WP7 (Lumia 800) as well, but not on my iPhone 4 either Samsung Galaxy Nexus (android) :( -  I have not even a single line of javascript, just the `bootstrap.js` to work with the modal, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the "bugger"

it's the **Modal** that is on top and block access to everything else in back... adding `hide`  to the modal class solves the problem.